# What's wrong with the following amchart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to plot the graph using amchart in a coldfusion file but wondering why nothing is displayed in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cfchart</title>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--- August 01 --->
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart;

var chartData = [{
    date: 2013-07-31,
    FIRSTCONN: 3,
    SECONDCONN: 4
    },

{
    date: 2013-08-15,
    FIRSTCONN: 5,
    SECONDCONN: 10
    },


    date: 2013-08-17,
    FIRSTCONN: 6,
    SECONDCONN: 8
    }

    ];


    AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.marginRight = 0;
    chart.autoMarginOffset = 5;
    chart.categoryField = "date";
    chart.startDuration = 0.5;
    chart.balloon.color = "#000000";


    // AXES
    // category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.fillAlpha = 1;
    categoryAxis.fillColor = "#FAFAFA";
    categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
    categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
    categoryAxis.position = "top";


     // value
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.title = "Number of Connections";
    valueAxis.dashLength = 5;
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    valueAxis.minimum = 1;
    valueAxis.maximum = 6;
    valueAxis.integersOnly = true;
    valueAxis.gridCount = 10;
    valueAxis.reversed = true; // this line makes the value axis reversed
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);



// GRAPHS
    // FIRST Connection graph                                            
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "FIRST";
    graph.valueField = "FIRSTCONN";
    graph.hidden = true; // this line makes the graph initially hidden           
    graph.balloonText = "Number of FIRST connections [[category]]: [[value]]";
    graph.lineAlpha = 1;
    graph.bullet = "round";
    chart.addGraph(graph);



    // GRAPHS
    // SECOND Connection graph                                            
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "SECOND";
    graph.valueField = "SECONDCONN";
    graph.hidden = true; // this line makes the graph initially hidden           
    graph.balloonText = "Number of SECOND connections [[category]]: [[value]]";
    graph.lineAlpha = 1;
    graph.bullet = "round";
    chart.addGraph(graph);


     // LEGEND
    var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    legend.markerType = "circle";
    chart.addLegend(legend);


     // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");



    });


</script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 362px;"></div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged for ColdFusion? There is nothing ColdFusion related in the code.

Comment: I've removed the ColdFusion-oriented tags, which were incorrect. Tan, are you getting any Javascript errors? What's coming out in the console view?

Comment: When I ran the code as is, I saw a JS error in the console that showed me what line the error was on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a { in your code.

The 3rd block of data should look like

```
{
date: 2013-08-17,
FIRSTCONN: 6,
SECONDCONN: 8
}
```

Comment: This raises the question of what dev environment are you using to code with, Tan? Because I just pasted that code into ColdFusion Builder (ie: not a JS editor), and it highlighted where the error is. This code should have a) rung alarms bells in your IDE; b) raised errors in the browser. Are you not paying attention to this sort of thing?

Comment: Thanks Scott. I was missing the { in my code. @Adam, I have Debugging options enables in the coldfusion administrator and I didnt' see any missingg { related error on my browser. I checked the Web Console now by deliberating leaving the { . I saw the following:`
[13:49:24.015] SyntaxError: 08 is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant @ http://dev.telespeech.com/akhare/Amchart/hwtowork.cfm:18
[13:49:24.015] SyntaxError: missing ] after element list @ http://dev.telespeech.com/akhare/Amchart/hwtowork.cfm:24`

Comment: By the way why I'm seeing year on the x-axis instead of dates I have mentioned for "date" field? I'm seeing 1975,1990,1988

Comment: Tan, there's no ColdFusion code there... it's all HTML and JS. So CF debugging is completely irrelevant. *ColdFusion* is completely irrelevant here. What IDE are you using for your code? If you're writing JS (and you're not sufficiently comfortable with it to notice fundamental syntax errors), you should be using an appropriate tool for the job. Situations like this should seriously never get as far as being asked on Stack Overflow: you're not doing the minimum "due diligence" of your own before posting.

Comment: I see. In that case, I'm just using Dreamweaver. That's it.

Comment: Actually, eventually, I'm gonna use JS in a coldfusion files for getting the results from the recordset and use them for displaying the graph and hence I'm wondering how can I use two editors, Dreamweaver and other for JS at the same time? OR any other alternative ?

Comment: BTW putting the category dates in double quotes did show the actual dates. Still wondering why it was showing 1975,1990,1998.

Comment: @Tan - When you are working with JavaScript, you should use Firebug (if using Firefox) or Chrome Developer Tools (is using Chrome). Using Chrome Developer Tools I was able to find the issue in as long as it took me to copy/paste/save/run your code. If I may, it seems you are VERY new to web development. You may want to take some time to familiarize yourself with some of the technologies instead of trying to learn Via StackOverflow.

Comment: @ScottStroz I could not agree with you more. This site is not a tutorial system. Tan, when you have the code above open in DreamWeaver, does it not highlight where the syntax error is? I find that hard to believe (although cannot test). But at any rate, you need to simply pay attention to what you're doing, rather than expecting the community to do it for you. Stack Overflow is *not* a programming version of "Care in the Community".